# Using 'select' option in react query paginated queries to filter by category

Tags: reactjs, mern, react-query

I have made a meme generator app and the following is the path for client to select a template:

```
`//localhost:3001/select-template?page=${pageNumber}`.
```

Fetching the data:

```
const { data, isLoading, isFetching } = useQuery(
    ["images", pageNumber],
    () => fetchImages(pageNumber),
    {
      keepPreviousData: true,
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
      select: 'Need help with this'
    }
  );
```

The response from the api is in the following format:

```
{
all_Images: (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
page: "0"
totalItems: 18
totalPages: 2
};
```

This is the first time I am using React query. What I would like to do is:

Utilising the 'select' option and be able to use the js filter() method to display images based on the category selected from a dropdown box.

Here is an example code to give you an idea of what I want to achieve:

```
select: (images) => images.filter((img) => img.category.includes(cat)).
```

I will be very grateful to whoever takes the time to assist me with this.

Comment: What result did you get? Show debugging details

Comment: @LinDu So this is what I tried doing: 
select: (data) =>
        data.all_Images.filter((img) => img.category.includes(cat));
This however changes the response immediately to render only the first page.